# React with D3 - Only rendering new items without updating or removing old ones

Tags: javascript, reactjs, d3.js, react-hooks, render

I have created a size legend that works as intended apart from the fact that when I make a change to it e.g. update the data - the old version stays rendered and a new version is rendered over the top. How can I achieve updating, adding and removing elements as D3 was intended?

I understand that React and D3 both want to control the DOM so can be difficult to work with together, and my code so far has come from a non-react tutorial - so I believe the error must be something to do with the way I am using React and D3 together.

Here is my code

```
import React, { useRef, useEffect } from 'react';
import { select, scaleSqrt } from 'd3';

function D3SizeBar(props) {

    const svgRef = useRef();

    useEffect(() => {

        const sizeLegend = (selection, props) => {
            const {
                sizeScale,
                spacing,
                textOffset,
                numTicks,
                circleFill
            } = props;
        
        const ticks = sizeScale.ticks(numTicks).filter(d => d !== 0)
        
        const groups = selection.selectAll('g').data(ticks);
    
        const groupsEnter = groups.enter().append('g');
    
        groupsEnter
            .merge(groups)
            .attr(`transform`, (d, i) =>
                `translate(0, ${i * spacing})`
            );
    
        groups
            .exit()
            .remove();
        
        groupsEnter
            .append('circle')
            .merge(groups.select('circle'))
            .attr('r', sizeScale)
            .attr('fill', circleFill)
        
        groupsEnter
            .append('text')
            .merge(groups.select('text'))
            .text(d => d)
            .attr('dy', '0.32em')
            .attr('x', d => sizeScale(d) + textOffset)
        }

        const data = [0, 0]
        data.splice(0, 1, Math.max.apply(Math, props.sValueArray))
        data.splice(1, 1, Math.min.apply(Math, props.sValueArray))
        console.log(data)

        const sizeScale = scaleSqrt()
            .domain(data)
            .range([20, 5])

        const svg = select(svgRef.current);
        svg
            .append('g')
            .attr('transform', `translate(30,20)`)
            .call(sizeLegend, {
                sizeScale,
                spacing: 25,
                textOffset: 10,
                numTicks: 3,
                circleFill: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)'
            }
        );
    }, [props.sValueArray]);

    return (
        <svg ref={svgRef}/>
    )
}

export default D3SizeBar;
```

If anyone is well versed enough in using React and D3 together I would really appreciate the help on where I am going wrong. `sValueArray' is just an array of numbers with max. value = 50 and min. value = 10.

An example of what this looks like is here, this is changing the spacing from 25 to 30.

[image: D3SizeBar component when spacing is changed from 25 to 30]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because you didn’t clear the element’s content before adding others within it.

You were taking the `ref` from the`<svg />`element, and selecting the element via`d3.select (ref.current)`, but the `ref` remained the same each time `useEffect` is run , and right when you ran `select (ref.current)` it already had children. Because every time `React` sent a new web update, `useEffect` was updated and `ref` remained the same.

#### Solution

You can simply clean up all the children present in the parent `svg` always before adding a new object:

```js
svg.selectAll("*").remove();
```

#### Code

```
import React, { useRef, useEffect } from 'react';
import { select, scaleSqrt } from 'd3';

function D3SizeBar(props) {

    const svgRef = useRef();

    useEffect(() => {

        const sizeLegend = (selection, { sizeScale,
            spacing,
            textOffset,
            numTicks,
            circleFill }) => {

            const ticks = sizeScale.ticks(numTicks).filter(d => d !== 0)

            const groups = selection.selectAll('g').data(ticks);

            const groupsEnter = groups.enter().append('g');

            groupsEnter
                .merge(groups)
                .attr(`transform`, (d, i) =>
                    `translate(0, ${i * spacing})`
                );

            groups
                .exit()
                .remove();

            groupsEnter
                .append('circle')
                .merge(groups.select('circle'))
                .attr('r', sizeScale)
                .attr('fill', circleFill)

            groupsEnter
                .append('text')
                .merge(groups.select('text'))
                .text(d => d)
                .attr('dy', '0.32em')
                .attr('x', d => sizeScale(d) + textOffset)
        }

        const data = [0, 0]
        data.splice(0, 1, Math.max.apply(Math, props.sValueArray))
        data.splice(1, 1, Math.min.apply(Math, props.sValueArray))
        console.log(data)

        const sizeScale = scaleSqrt()
            .domain(data)
            .range([20, 5])

        const svg = select(svgRef.current);
        svg.selectAll("*").remove() // add this before the append.
        svg
            .append('g')
            .attr('transform', `translate(30,20)`)
            .call(sizeLegend, {
                sizeScale,
                spacing: 50,
                textOffset: 10,
                numTicks: 3,
                circleFill: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)'
            }
            );
    }, [props.sValueArray]);

    return (
        <svg ref={svgRef} />
    )
}

export default D3SizeBar;
```

Answer (score 0):

You really don't want to remove everything. You want to reselect them and update the properties that need to be updated.